# Se produce un error en lectura de datos con InputStreamReader()

Tags: java

Cuando le pido en el ejercicio la opcion al principio el ejercicio va bien y se introduce en la opcion pero después lo que hace es entrar directamente el catch al llegar al leer la opción, por eso he puesto un break para que acabe ahí el programa y no se quede en el bucle (que es lo que pasaría). Me gustaría que funcionará como un bucle normal pidiéndome el número y ejecutando el método introduciéndo la cadena, el entero o lo que sea introduciéndolo por teclado hasta que introduzca el 0 que ya si debería salir definitivamente.

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Ejercicio {

    public static void leerCadena(){
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
            System.out.println("Introduce una cadena");
            String cadena = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(cadena);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error al leer cadena");
        }
    }

    public static void leerCaracter(){
        try (BufferedReader lectura = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
            System.out.println("Introduce un caracter");
            char caracter = lectura.readLine().charAt(0);
            System.out.println(caracter);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error");
        }
    }

    public static void leerEntero(){
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
            System.out.println("Introduce un numero: ");
            String lectura = br.readLine();
            int entero = Integer.parseInt(lectura);
            System.out.println(entero);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error al leer archivo");
        }
    }

    public static void leerShort(){
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
            System.out.println("Introduce un numero: ");
            String lectura = br.readLine();
            short lecturaShort = Short.parseShort(lectura);
            System.out.println(lecturaShort);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error al leer archivo");
        }
    }

    public static void leerDouble(){
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
            System.out.println("Introduce un numero: ");
            String lectura = br.readLine();
            double lecturaShort = Double.parseDouble(lectura);
            System.out.println(lecturaShort);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error al leer archivo");
        }
    }

    public static void leerFloat(){
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
            System.out.println("Introduce un numero: ");
            String lectura = br.readLine();
            float lecturaShort = Float.parseFloat(lectura);
            System.out.println(lecturaShort);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error al leer archivo");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(true){
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
                System.out.println("Menú\n\n"+
                "--------\n"+
                "1. Leer una cadena de texto.\n"+
                "2. Leer un caracter.\n"+
                "3. Leer un entero.\n"+
                "4. Leer un Short.\n"+
                "5. Leer un Double.\n"+
                "6. Leer un Float.\n"+
                "0. Salir.");
                String lectura = br.readLine();
                int opcion = Integer.parseInt(lectura);
                switch(opcion){
                        case 1:
                            Ejercicio.leerCadena();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Ejercicio.leerCaracter();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            Ejercicio.leerEntero();
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            Ejercicio.leerShort();
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            Ejercicio.leerDouble();
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            Ejercicio.leerFloat();
                            break;
                        case 0:
                            System.out.println("Saliendo");
                }
            if(opcion==0)
                break;
                
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Error al leer");
                break;
            }

        
        }
    }
}
```

PD: Lo he probado haciendo el main en otra clase con Scanner y me da esta excepcion:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
        at ficheros_III.Clase.main(Clase.java:18)
```

Comment: también se puede hacer así, además ese no es el error. Yo lo suelo poner así if(opcion==0)  
         break;    -> dentro del while

Comment: Pero es que a lo que me refiero es que el error no es ese porque no me vuelve a pedir la opción, así que no arregla absolutamente nada.

Comment: No se puede hacer el ejercicio con Scanner ya que la intención del ejercicio es hacerlo con BufferedReader, y eso de poner el bufferedReader en try-catch se llama try with resources y es para que se cierre automaticamente el buffered sin tener que cerrrarlo tu manualmente.

Comment: El ejercicio lo he arreglado más o menos con ChatGPT y me va poniendo el buffered como un atributo estático de la clase que comparten todos los métodos y el mismo. De todas maneras si alguien pudiese ayudarme a entender porqué eso me va mal y el error que hace que no vaya en el main vamos...le doy la vida.

Comment: Y de todas maneras gracias Marce.

Comment: Estoy probando todo lo que se me ocurre, lo último fue poner **br.close();** detrás de **int opcion = Integer.parseInt( lectura );** entra al switch y me arroja error en el **leerAlgo**, eso quiere decir que esta usando el mismo **BufferedReader** en todos los casos, tal vez por eso se soluciona poniéndolo como estático, corrijo, lo de estatico lo pone porque estás en el main, si no no lo puedes invocar, el secreto es que tiene que ser un único bufer... creo.

Comment: Efectivamente, para que funcione lo tienes que declarar como variable global (atributo), no olvides corregir la condición del `while` a **opcion != 0** (declarando opcion antes del mismo) o en el **case 0** cambiar **break** por **return**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es el Código ya funcionando, el único problema es que el try  cerraba también el System.in,  yo lo solucione quitando la creación el objeto br del try resource y volverlo variable global y estática para poder ser utilizada en los métodos.

System.in es una variable estática de tipo InputStream que en tu Código es usada en todos los métodos y cuando un método terminaba de ocuparla cerraba la variable haciendo que ningún otro método pudiera usarla de nuevo

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/**
 *
 * @author hamoncho
 */
public class Main {
static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
     public static void leerCadena(){
        try  {
            System.out.println("Introduce una cadena");
            String cadena = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(cadena);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error al leer cadena");
        }
    }

    public static void leerCaracter(){
        try  {
            System.out.println("Introduce un caracter");
            char caracter = br.readLine().charAt(0);
            System.out.println(caracter);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error");
        }
    }

    public static void leerEntero(){
        try  {
            System.out.println("Introduce un numero: ");
            String lectura = br.readLine();
            int entero = Integer.parseInt(lectura);
            System.out.println(entero);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error al leer archivo");
        }
    }

    public static void leerShort(){
        try  {
            System.out.println("Introduce un numero: ");
            String lectura = br.readLine();
            short lecturaShort = Short.parseShort(lectura);
            System.out.println(lecturaShort);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error al leer archivo");
        }
    }

    public static void leerDouble(){
        try  {
            System.out.println("Introduce un numero: ");
            String lectura = br.readLine();
            double lecturaShort = Double.parseDouble(lectura);
            System.out.println(lecturaShort);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error al leer archivo");
        }
    }

    public static void leerFloat(){
        try {
            System.out.println("Introduce un numero: ");
            String lectura = br.readLine();
            float lecturaShort = Float.parseFloat(lectura);
            System.out.println(lecturaShort);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error al leer archivo");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int opcion = -1;
        
        while(opcion != 0){
             
            try {
               
                System.out.println("Menú\n\n"+
                "--------\n"+
                "1. Leer una cadena de texto.\n"+
                "2. Leer un caracter.\n"+
                "3. Leer un entero.\n"+
                "4. Leer un Short.\n"+
                "5. Leer un Double.\n"+
                "6. Leer un Float.\n"+
                "0. Salir.");
                
                String lectura = br.readLine();
                
                opcion = Integer.parseInt(lectura);
                switch(opcion){
                        case 1:
                           
                            Main.leerCadena();
                             //br.read();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Main.leerCaracter();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            Main.leerEntero();
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            Main.leerShort();
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            Main.leerDouble();
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            Main.leerFloat();
                            break;
                        case 0:
                            System.out.println("Saliendo");
                }
                    
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                opcion = 0;
                //break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias. interesante... Supongo entonces que si voy a leer buffer de varios métodos no cierro el buffer, hasta que finalmente lo vaya a cerrar y no volver a usar.